# Sorting using d3js

Tags: json, d3.js

I want to sort my json data in ascending order which has title, price. 
want to sort by price.

This my json data which is used in d3js.

```
var data = [
{"title":"ACER Aspire DQ.SP3EK.001 ZS 605 Refurbished 19.5\u201d All-in-One PC",
"price":"<549.99"},
{"title":"LENOVO C540 23\u201d Touchscreen All-in-One PC","price":"699.99"},
{"title":"ACER Aspire V5-122P 11.6\u201d Touchscreen Laptop/u2013silver","price" :"499.99"},
{"title":"HP Pavilion 15-n097ea 15.6 Laptop \u2013 Goji Berry","price":"429.99"},
{"title":"SONY Vaio Fit 15 E SVF1521A1EW.CEK 15\u201d Laptop \u2013 White","price":"399.99"}

]
```

I have done so far:

```
 var container = gallery.selectAll('.searchcontainer')
.data(data, function(d) { return d.title; });

container.enter().append('div')
.attr('class', 'searchcontainer')

container.exit().remove();

container.selectAll('ttl')
.data(function(d) { return [d]; })
.enter().append('div')
.attr('class', 'ttl')
.style('float','right')
.style('margin-top','-20px')
.style('margin-right','20px')
.style('width','80%')
.html(function(d) { return d.title; });

container.selectAll('.pricess')
.data(function(d) { return [d]; })
.enter().append('div')
.attr('class', 'pricess')
.style('float','right')
.style('width','10%')
.style('margin-bottom','10px')
.sort(d3.ascending())
.html(function(d) { return d.price; });
```

Comment: You would need `.sort(d3.ascending(function(d) { return d.price; }))`, but that won't work properly with the string. I would recommend having only the actual number in your JSON and then doing the formatting elsewhere.

Comment: Yes i have tried that but it not worked for me,i have nearly 40 records in json.

Comment: As I've said, try having the price only as the number. The number of records doesn't matter.

Comment: i have tried that too. but it doesn't worked for me.

Comment: Could you post code and data of what you have tried please?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Lars Kotthoff i have edited my code and updated the complete code which i am using for it.

Comment: Have you tried the additional argument to the sort function, like I've suggested?

Comment: yes i have tried that too.

Comment: Well, turns out I was wrong about the additional argument to the comparator -- sorry about that. Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xpm3x/) what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much @Lars Kotthoff for it i am looking for same.

Comment: Ok, I'll add it as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can sort the array by passing a comparator function to `.sort()`:

```
var container = gallery.selectAll('.searchcontainer')
  .data(data.sort(function(a,b) { return +a.price - +b.price; }),
    function(d) { return d.title; });
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xpm3x/).

Comment: if my json is this [{"price": "<ins>&pound;1,499.99</ins>"}, {"price": "<ins>&pound;1,199.99</ins>"},{"price": "<ins>&pound;99.99</ins>"}] and use to sort this then its sorting after comma value why...??? the output is shown:
£1,999.99
£1,499.99 
£99.99
but i orignal it should display:
£99.99
£1,499.99
£1,999.99

Comment: This is the string sort order. If you want numerical order, you have to use numbers (the data type).