# D3.JS sort datapoints high to low?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm using D3.JS for my project and am not sure how I can sort the incoming data. I have the following coming in from my API:

```
[
  {
    "target": "target_one",
    "datapoints": [
      [
        8.0,
        1493510400.0
      ],
      [
        8.0,
        1493596800.0
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "target": "target_two",
    "datapoints": [
      [
        1.0,
        1493510400.0
      ],
      [
        1.0,
        1493596800.0
      ],
      [
        10.0,
        1493683200.0
      ]
    ]
  },
]
```

Is there a way using d3 that I can sort this data high to low? Any suggestions at all would be great, thanks!

Comment: You can do a data.sort with d3 after you receive the data as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185559/sorting-using-d3js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting using d3js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185559/sorting-using-d3js)

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with raw javascript, using this prototype function

```
Array.prototype.orderByDescending = function (func) {
    this.sort((a, b) => {
        var a = func(a);
        var b = func(b);
        if (typeof a === 'string' || a instanceof String) {
            return b.localeCompare(a);
        }
        return b - a;
    });
    return this;
}
```

and invoke it like that

`elements.forEach(element=>{ element.datapoints.orderByDescending(p => p[0]) })`

Or if you prefer to not pollute prototype , you can use normal function

```
function orderByDescending (array,func) {
    array.sort((a, b) => {
        var a = func(a);
        var b = func(b);
        if (typeof a === 'string' || a instanceof String) {
            return b.localeCompare(a);
        }
        return b - a;
    });
    return array;
}
```

and invoke it like that

`elements.forEach(element=>{ orderByDescending(element.datapoints, p =>p [0])})`

Snippet

```js
Array.prototype.orderByDescending = function (func) {
    this.sort((a, b) => {
        var a = func(a);
        var b = func(b);
        if (typeof a === 'string' || a instanceof String) {
            return b.localeCompare(a);
        }
        return b - a;
    });
    return this;
}

var elements = [
  {
    "target": "target_one",
    "datapoints": [
      [
        8.0,
        1493510400.0
      ],
      [
        8.0,
        1493596800.0
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "target": "target_two",
    "datapoints": [
      [
        1.0,
        1493510400.0
      ],
      [
        1.0,
        1493596800.0
      ],
      [
        10.0,
        1493683200.0
      ]
    ]
  },
]

// order by  [0] point
elements.forEach(element=>{
    element.datapoints.orderByDescending(p=>p[0])
})

console.log('ordered descending by first element')
console.log(JSON.stringify(elements));

// order by  [1] point
elements.forEach(element=>{
    element.datapoints.orderByDescending(p=>p[1])
})

console.log('ordered descending by second element')
console.log(JSON.stringify(elements));
```

Comment: Should I sort before passing to d3?

Comment: As I understand question, yes, it should be sorted before

Comment: I would suggest not polluting the Array prototype. It's generally a bad idea to override system objects that might be updated in future browser versions. You can just declare it as a normal function.

Refer to https://esdiscuss.org/topic/array-prototype-contains-solutions

Comment: I agree with you , although  this way is more cleaner in the code. Anyway, I also have added that option in the answer